# Convert from polar to cartesian

Tags: complex-numbers

I am facing this problem:

**Turn into cartesian form:**

$$\dfrac{1-e^{i\pi/2}}{1 + e^{i\pi/2}}$$

I've tried to operate and I've come up to this:

$$\dfrac{1-2e^{i\pi/2} + e^{i\pi}}{1 - e^{i\pi}}$$

I do not know how to go on, and I've tried to operate with the cartesian form of the initial quotient, but I come up with an expression similar. I'm stucked.

Comment: use the $$e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}=i$$

Comment: I had, and I could solve it. I didn't realised it. thank you so much! @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the equivalence mentioned above, we get:

$$
\frac{1+i}{1-i}= \frac{e^\frac{7\pi}{4}}{e^\frac{\pi}{4}} = e^\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Then we convert the polar form into cartesian so we end up with:
 $e^\frac{\pi}{2}$ $\rightarrow$ -*i*

Answer (score 0):

As follows,

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1-e^{i\pi/2}}{1 + e^{i\pi/2}}
&=\frac{1-i}{1+i}\\
&=\frac{(1-i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}\\
&=\frac{-2i}{2}\\
&=-i
\end{align}
$$